# plsql code to replace values of a column with characters

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

if there is a name column

```
name

prashant

ram
```

then the column values should  become like this
name

```
##############################
# Name     |  Replaced_value #
##############################   
# prashant |    XXXXXXXX     #
#          |                 #
# ram      |    XXX          #
##############################
```

It has to replaced by same number of Xs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work !!

```
select name,substr(lpad(name,length(name)+length(name),'X'),1,length(name)) as replaced_name from table
```

Comment: but what if we have to replace the names in the database with Xs.this statement will show the output with Xs.what if we need to store it in database with Xs.

Comment: u mean u need to update the previous names in table with the X's
then use an update statement like

`update table a set name= (select substr(lpad(name,length(name)+length(name),'X'),1,length(name)) from table b where a.name=b.name);`

Comment: or else if you want to just display output two columns then

`select name,substr(lpad(name,length(name)+length(name),'X'),1,length(name)) as replaced_name from table `

Answer (score 3):

You can combine lpad/rpad and length

```
LPAD('X',LENGTH(InputString),'X')
```